# Initializing the php form created with Formtools.org

Tags: php, forms, api, initialization

I'm working on a form with Form tools http://www.formtools.org
My task is to create php multi-page form, using their API. And it should also save data after every step, not only after the last one.

But I already have a problem while initializing the form into the system.

I have all pages built, and when I'm doing test submission it works good. I successfully see my 'Thank you page'.
Following is the code from my 1st page

```
<?php
require_once("/app-administration/global/api/api.php");
$fields = ft_api_init_form_page("", "test");
$params = array(
"submit_button" => "submit",
"next_page" => "lc_2.php",
"form_data" => $_POST
);
ft_api_process_form($params);
?>
```

Then, due to the tutorial, I go to the admin panned, create new form there. And then, I need to initialize it.
So, I'm changing this line:

```
$fields = ft_api_init_form_page(12, "initialize");
```

But then, when I try to submit the form I get 100 error on the last page:
http://docs.formtools.org/api/index.php?page=error_codes#100

It says there is something with ID, but 12 is correct one because I have it from admin panel, and I double-checked it there.

Anybody have any ideas why I might have this error? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks